# Optimze GPU performance of virtual server

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016

In our company, we have used VMware server virtualization in order to divide a physical server into multiple unique and isolated virtual servers. One of those virtual servers (OS: Windows Server 2016) is used for application publishing meaning that several applications are installed on it which can be run by multiple client machines.

We found out that the GPU performance (VMware SVGA 3D) is very poor when clients run that applications.

What could be done in order to improve the GPU performance?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated GPU for this guest, or a slice of one with VDI capable "virtual GPU"? Do you have Citrix XenApp with its many accelerations?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to clarify this. What would be the optimal setup in your opinion?

Comment: On the virtual server there is nothing installed regarding Citrix.

Comment: No, there is no dedicated GPU per  client using application publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a decision about how much you want to invest in this graphics experience. Then evaluate application publishing technologies and think carefully about what GPU and hypervisor you want to use.

For better performance, use accelerated graphics.  You may be able to get acceptable results with the "VMware SVGA 3D" software rendering you have now, but it requires significant CPU.

VMware can present dedicated or shared GPUs to guests. Reference their [Virtual Machine Graphics Acceleration Deployment Guide](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/whitepaper/vmware-horizon-view-graphics-acceleration-deployment-white-paper.pdf). Their use case is  Horizon View VDI, but it has practical examples of shared GPUs.

RDSH can also take advantage of RemoteFX vGPU, but I'm pretty sure that requires Hyper-V hypervisor.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for this. Our application publishing service supports VMware ESXi and Hyper-V. What would be the best solutions regarding performance from your point of view not considering the cost.

Comment: I don't have much practical experience in published apps, and you need to define your requirements anyway. Talk to VMware or Microsoft or Citrix and say you need a better published app experience.